# Using single quote (') in shell script - RSYNC woes

Tags: linux, shell

I think I have a simple problem I don't seem to be-able to find a solution to myself :-D

I am creating a shell script in linux (debian 10) using /bin/bash shell. Lines 1 & 2 below is the code. I am changing the default ssh port, however the single quotes I have put around 'ssh -p $PORT' for $SSH_CMD are translating into something weird, also see below for output lines 3 & 4. Any ideas how I can turn my single quotes into actual single quotes for the rsync line to work? Cheers.

```
SSH_CMD="-e 'ssh -p $PORT'"
rsync $SSH_CMD --chmod=a=rw,Da+x -trv $rsync_target/$target/manifest.csv $pendingdir/$target --delete

SSH_CMD='-e '\''ssh -p 46000'\'''
rsync -e ''\''ssh' -p '46000'\''' --chmod=a=rw,Da+x -trv hexfeed@79.173.143.202::download /ssd/rsync --delete
```

Comment: Have you tried single quote with double escape?  `\\'`

Comment: ... Or escaped double quotes.

Comment: @Zak \\' gives me `rsync --timeout=10 -e '\'\''ssh' -p '46000\'\'''`

Comment: Feed `#!/bin/bash
SSH_CMD="-e 'ssh -p $PORT'"` into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and enjoy the output ...

Comment: Post reduce your example to the minimal next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the variable expansion ($SSH_CMD), you want the shell to interpret the single quotes, and this is done via `eval`. Please see the following minimal example that works:

```
PORT=22
SSH_CMD="-e 'ssh -p $PORT'"
cmd="rsync $SSH_CMD /tmp/eval.sh test-w1:/tmp/"
echo $cmd
eval $cmd
```

Before you run it, you can echo out the command, and see if it is the command that you would type directly on the shell prompt.